# Data on SQL Server Management Studio is not Updating

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

something's wrong with my code here on Visual Studio 2012. It is supposed to update the records which can be found on my SQL Server Management Studio. Everything is consistent with the DB except for this update. Please take a look at my code:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        if (txtPassword.Text == "")
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET EmailAddress=@EmailAddress, FirstName=@FirstName, " +
                "LastName=@LastName, Street=@Street, Municipality=@Municipality, City=@City, ZipCode=@ZipCode, ContactNo=@ContactNo, Image=@Image " +
                "WHERE UserID=@UserID";
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET Password=@Password, EmailAddress=@EmailAddress, FirstName=@FirstName, " +
               "LastName=@LastName, Address=@Address, Street=@Street, Municipality=@Municipality, City=@City, ZipCode=@ZipCode, ContactNo=@ContactNo, Image=@Image " +
               "WHERE UserID=@UserID";
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFN.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLN.Text;
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Street", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStreet.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Municipality", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMunicipality.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCity.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ZipCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtZipCode.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtContact.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        if (fuImage.HasFile)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "~/images/" + fuImage.FileName;
            fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + fuImage.FileName));
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Text).Value = imgAvatar.ImageUrl;
        }

        Helper.AddLog(Session["UserID"].ToString(), "Update", "Updated a User");
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }

    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: You do not execute the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to execute the query

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```